# Is ResNet34 available in Keras.application?

Tags: python, keras, resnet

I would like to wrap a keras ResNet34 model, but there seems to be only ResNet50 which can be imported from keras.applications. Is there a way that I can import ResNet34 directly instead of building one?

I found the following codes online, but I am wondering where the `classification_models.models.resnet.ResNet34` came from? Does it have anything to do with Keras?

```
import keras
from classification_models.keras import Classifiers

ResNet34, preprocess_input = Classifiers.get('resnet34')
```

I would appreciate your suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming , you have the code snippet from the link - https://github.com/qubvel/classification_models, classification_models.models.resnet.ResNet34 has nothing to do with keras. Additionally, there's no way that you can import ResNet34 from  keras.applications.